# Поведение match в JavaScript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, match, javascript

Всем привет. Снова немного о регулярных выражениях в JS.
Я ожидаю, что код:

```
'aabb'.match(/a.*b/g);
```

, вернет мне массив:

```
['aab', 'aabb', 'ab', 'abb'];
```

Почему он возвращает массив только с одним элементом?

```
['aabb']
```

Разве `str.match(RegExp);` не должен возвращать массив всех совпадений по регулярному выражению?

Comment: Регулярные выражения ищут не совпадения, а подстроки в строке, которым удовлетворял бы заданный шаблон. При этом есть жадный и ленивый поиск, которые по разному обрабатывают приведенный вами пример.

Comment: Как мне добиться ожидаемого массива?

Comment: Регулярные выражения не предназначены для подобных действий, все таки он ищет подстроки по шаблону, а не все совпадения. Придется сделать поиск каждого такого выражения отдельно, при этом для экономии можно выделить группировкой условия в существующих.

Answer (score 11):

Надо объединить возможности регулярных выражений, такие как жадный и ленивый поиск, захват подстроки в блоке просмотра и глобальный модификатор:

```js
re = /(?=(a.*?b))(?=(a.*b))/g;
s = 'aabb';
arr = [];
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null)  {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1] && arr.indexOf(m[1]) === -1)
    arr.push(m[1]);
  if (m[2] && arr.indexOf(m[2]) === -1)
    arr.push(m[2]);
  
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

В данном случае, выражение при нахождении совпадения вернет пустой результат в `m[0]`, но благодаря подмаскам в `m[1]` и `m[2]` будут извлечены захваченные подстроки. Так как эти подстроки могут быть идентичны, необходима проверка существующих элементов.

**ОТВЕТ НА КОММЕНТАРИЙ:**

Для поиска всех пермутаций на основе любого шаблона, можно воспользоваться следующим кодом. Его особенность: собираем все совпадения, а потом последовательно определяем, есть ли совпадения внутри совпадения. Таким образом, *нет необходимости проверять абсолютно все пермутации входной строки.*

```
function permRegex(re_str, s) {
  var arr = [];                              // Все наши пермутации
  var caps = [];                             // Все начальные совпадения (caps)
  var re = RegExp(re_str, "g");              // Глобальное выражение для caps
  while ((m = re.exec(s)) !== null) {        // Ищем...
    caps.push(m[0]);                         // и добавляем совпадение в caps
  }
  var re2 = RegExp("^" + re_str + "$");      // Создаем неглобальное выражение для проверки на совпадение ЦЕЛОЙ строки
  for (var c=0; c<caps.length; c++)          // Перебираем наши совпадения
    for(var i=0; i < caps[c].length; i++)     // От первого символа...
      for(var j=i+1; j <= caps[c].length; j++) // До последнего, слева направо
        if(re2.test(str = caps[c].substring(i, j))) // Если совпадает с шаблоном
          arr.push(str);                       // Добавляем к пермутациям

  return arr;
}

document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(permRegex("a.*b", "aabb")) + "<br/>";
// "aabb"  => ["aabb", "aab", "abb", "ab"]
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(permRegex("a.*b", "aabbb")) + "<br/>";
// "aabbb" => ["aabbb", "aabb", "aab", "abbb", "abb", "ab"]
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(permRegex("е.*т", "А где енот?"));
// "е.*т", "А где енот?" => ["е енот", "енот"]
```

```js
function permRegex(re_str, s) {
  var arr = [];                              // Все наши пермутации
  var caps = [];                             // Все начальные совпадения (caps)
  var re = RegExp(re_str, "g");              // Глобальное выражение для caps
  while ((m = re.exec(s)) !== null) {        // Ищем...
    caps.push(m[0]);                         // и добавляем совпадение в caps
  }
  var re2 = RegExp("^" + re_str + "$");      // Создаем неглобальное выражение для проверки на совпадение ЦЕЛОЙ строки
  for (var c=0; c<caps.length; c++)          // Перебираем наши совпадения
    for(var i=0; i < caps[c].length; i++)     // От первого символа...
      for(var j=i+1; j <= caps[c].length; j++) // До последнего, слева направо
        if(re2.test(str = caps[c].substring(i, j))) // Если совпадает с шаблоном
          arr.push(str);                       // Добавляем к пермутациям
  
  return arr;
}

document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(permRegex("a.*b", "aabb")) + "<br/>";
// "aabb"  => ["aabb", "aab", "abb", "ab"]
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(permRegex("a.*b", "aabbb")) + "<br/>";
// "aabbb" => ["aabbb", "aabb", "aab", "abbb", "abb", "ab"]
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(permRegex("е.*т", "А где енот?"));
// "е.*т", "А где енот?" => ["е енот", "енот"]

$( "#run" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#a1" ).html( JSON.stringify(permRegex( $( "#regex" ).val(), $( "#text" ).val() ) ) );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="regex" placeholder="regex" /> <input id="text" placeholder="text" /><br/>
<button id="run">Ok</button>
<div id="a1"/>
```

Comment: А если `aabbbb` ?

Comment: Тогда используем альтернативный способ и получаем `["aabbb", "aabb", "aab", "abbb", "abb", "ab"]`.

Comment: Отличный результат.

Comment: Плохо добавлять захватываемые группы - поломаются запросы в стиле `(.)\1*`.

Comment: `"е.*т", "А где енот?" => ["е енот", " енот", "енот"]` что-то лишнее

Comment: Нет, всё правильно, если следовать логике вопроса. Не было условия относительно пробелов в начале или конце искомых подстрок.

Comment: Просто оно не соответствует выражению `е.*т`, потому что пробел в начале, а это уже не следует логике вопроса.

Comment: Зайду тогда с другого бока: `permRegex( "е.*т", "А гдеXенот?")`

Comment: @ReinRaus: Так же, как и в предыдущем случае: возвращаются все подстроки, совпадающие с оригинальным регулярным выражением: `["еXенот","Xенот","енот"]`. Лучше дать словесное определение того, что именно Вас не устраивает.

Comment: Результат «Хенот» не соответствует регулярному выражению «е.*т». Посмотрите вопрос внимательно. Требуется найти все СОВПАДЕНИЯ. «Хенот» не является совпадением.

Comment: Совпадение есть, так как регулярное выражение не имело "якорей". Нужно создать неглобальное выражение для проверки на совпадение ЦЕЛОЙ строки. Добавил `^` и `$`.

Comment: Совпадением называется текст, который ПОЛНОСТЬЮ удовлетворяет регулярному выражению. Никаких исключений. Никаких якорей. `Хенот` не удовлетворяет выражению `е.*т`

Comment: `permRegex( "a(.|cc)", "acc") // [ "ac" ]` :(

Comment: Всё правильно, `"a(.|cc)"` в строке `acc` может найти только `a` + символ, отличный от знака перевода строки (т.е. `ac`). Это ж не POSIX, где тестируются все альтернативы в поисках самого длинного вхождения.

Comment: но ведь хочется другого результата :)

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что хочется результатa `[ "ac", "acc" ]` а это не позикс, а сам алгоритм подхода к решению данной задачи...

Comment: Ну немножко не так... Хотелось, чтобы Вы внесли небольшие правки в Ваш ответ, чтобы это стало возможно, но ладно. Тогда это уже будет не Ваш ответ, а копия ответа @Qwertiy. Награжу лучше тогда ответ ниже, чтобы ответы не дублировали друг друга.

Comment: Изменил немного, скорее всего Вы вводили регулярное выражение без обрамления слэшами. Там логика принимающей функции такая- нужно принять регулярное выражение как аргумент. Проще всего заевалить вводимое  строковое значение.

Comment: Вся разница в том, что мой код принимает регексп и *не изменяя его* использует для поиска совпадений. Чтобы получить `["ac", "acc"]` при входном тексте `acc`, введите `^a(.|cc)$`. Изыски типа `r = RegExp('^(?:' + r.source + ')$', r.toString().replace(/^[\s\S]*\/(\w*)$/, '$1'));` излишни.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы получить все возможные подходящие подстроки, надо их вручную перебрать и каждую проверить на полное совпадение с выражением. Соответственно, к выражению надо добавить признаки начала и конца строки, но так, чтобы не сбились группы внутри.

```js
function doit(r, s) {
  var res = [], cur;
  r = RegExp('^(?:' + r.source + ')$', r.toString().replace(/^[\s\S]*\/(\w*)$/, '$1'));
  r.global = false;
  for (var q = 0; q < s.length; ++q)
    for (var w = q; w <= s.length; ++w)
      if (r.test(cur = s.substring(q, w)))
        res.push(cur);
  return res;
}

$( "#run" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#a1").text( JSON.stringify( doit(
    eval( $( "#regex" ).val() ),
    $( "#text" ).val()
    ) ) );
} );

doit( /a.*b/g, 'aabb' )   // Array [ "aab", "aabb", "ab", "abb" ]
doit( /a(.|cc)/g, 'acc' ) // Array ["ac","acc"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="regex" placeholder="/a.*b/" />
<input id="text" placeholder="aaabb" />
<br/>
<button id="run">Ok</button>
<div id="a1" />
```

Comment: Извините, что без Вашего позволения внес такие правки. Еще одна награда - Вам.

Comment: @ReinRaus, я не понимаю, как `r.toString().replace(/^[\s\S]*\/(\w*)$/, '$1'))` должно убирать флаг `g` из регулярки. Вероятно, правка неверна. И верни, пожалуйста, пустые строки обратно. А за награду - спасибо :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, сорри, я неправ - не заметил строку с присвоением флага. Впрочем, регулярка же передаётся по ссылке, т. е. такое присваивание в этом месте испортит регулярку вызывающего кода - нехорошо. Но можно переставить строки местами. А ещё не надо вызывать `html` там, где должен быть текст.

Answer (score 0):

Вы описали почти правильный ожидаемый результат для DFA механизма регулярных выражений (возможно вы перешли с другого языка где используется диалект регулярок с использованием этого устарелого механизма), но вот javaScript (а точнее браузеры) поддерживает NFA механизм, реализуется с помощью библиотеки PCRE (с урезанным функционалом).

- [подробней о механизмах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- [подробней о синтаксисе](http://pcre.org/pcre2.txt)
- [попробовать (подебажить)](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Comment: В языке JavaScript регулярные выражения - часть стандарта ECMA-262. Никак не PCRE. И как раз NFA.

Comment: @stribizhev да обьект Regexp описан в стандарте ECMA-262 по образу и подобию perl regex, но только "браузерные" движки выбрали pcre так как он не perl :) и писать снуля ненужно, в свою очередь разработчики pcre добавили константы javascript в свою либу. Выше сказанное я наблюдал в разных движках. Решил погуглить так ли это, был удивлен что хром изменил pcre http://blog.chromium.org/2009/02/irregexp-google-chromes-new-regexp.html. А вот по поводу NFA согласен, я перепутал местами (подправил ответ)

Comment: Так как "функционал" урезан донельзя, я бы не стал вообще упоминать PCRE в контексте JavaScript, это может сбить с толку тех, кто ещё не разбирается в тонкостях регулярных выражений.

Comment: не больше 50%, и в мане pcre частично указывают моменты для ECMAScript. Черт Spidermonkey походу в 2011 тоже был без pcre. Так как pcre это эталон в регулярках, то лучше сразу смотреть туда, имхо ихний ман читаеться намного проще ECMA-262

Comment: А как Вы подсчитали эти 50%? :)

Comment: 1) Насколько мне известно - DFA найдет максимальное по длине совпадение. Можете привести пример, где DFA находит все вхождения? http://ideone.com 2) Статья на Вики о регулярных выражениях бесполезна на 99% 3) Подробнее о синтаксисе - при чем здесь синтаксис, если Вы говорите о реализациях DFA и NFA? 4) Зачем даете ссылку на дебагер NFA, если говорите, что ТС спасет применение DFA?

Comment: это моя "ката", я раз в месяц прохожу по всем возможностям pcre, и сейчас чучуть пишу на js, и все время держу в голове разницу

Comment: @ReinRaus 1) вы меня рассекретили, большого опыта в dfa у меня нету, я и правда забыл о максимальной длине, а в текущем примере это имеет значение. 3) о синтаксисе я упомянул потому что считаю что человек ожидая такой результат писал раньше на регулярках из множества DFA и ему нужно переключиться на другой мануал. 4) потому что это единственный из мне известных онлайн дебагеров регулярок, который лучше объяснит как это работает именно для javascript. Я бы с удовольствием попробовал DFA и конкретные реализации, если покажете ссылки где он распространнен и как быстро можно его попробовать.

Comment: awk и egrep - самые популярные язык/утилита в которой используется именно ДКА.

Comment: вот grep -E я когдато пробывал, и был удивлен что результат был NFA,  попробую еще раз может, тогда что то перепутал

Comment: @ReinRaus это программы которые нормально отдебажить не выйдет, тут нужна не утилита а какой-нибудь высокоуровневый язык, например, может на java можно подключит именно дка регулярки, и подебажить. Например по поводу указанной выше регулярки, возможно можно получить каждую ветку поиска, без учета отбрасывания неподходящих.

Comment: А в чем разница ? Регулярные выражения везде одинаковые. Дебажить ничего не надо.

Comment: разница в том что можно добиться разного результата, например 2 года назад в pcre добавили возможность управлять курсором прямо из регулярки, то есть это решает выше указанную проблему, а при дка механизме у нас идет одновременный поиск по каждой ветки, но заканчиваеться одним максимальным совпадением, предполагаю что можно сохранить все успешные совпадения не потеряв производительности, это даст лично лучшее понимание что да как.

Comment: То есть нужно модифицировать имеющиеся движки ДКА, чтобы они могли служить такой цели?

Comment: А как записывается управление курсором? Не знал про такую фишку.

Comment: не записывает, а дает небольшой контроль http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html
 Удивительно то что это уже считаеться очень старым механизмом, даже в php поддерживаеться давным давно 28 August 2007. По поводу записи движения, в принципе можно заюзать http://www.rexegg.com/pcre-callouts.html

Comment: Можете привести регулярку PCRE, которая приведет к желаемому результату? Я не понял как это можно сделать используя `Backtracking Control Verbs`. Если сделаете это- то с меня награда.